# Azure mobile app| easy api| native androidapplication | options for authentication

Tags: android, azure

We are developing a native android app that had its own user login mechanism. We have the backend on azure and have developed APIs through easy api and easy table. Access to these apps will happen only through the native app, and we want to authenticate that by using some sort of certificate or token based mechanism. I had a look at the azure documents, which left me confused. Any one has any suggestions  or pointers?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I recommend that you can leverage token based mechanism. And you can make some modifications to let your mechanism to return JWT standard token. Because both Mobile App's SDK for server or for client, has predefined several authentication functionalities or middlewares (refer to https://azure.github.io/azure-mobile-apps-node/module-azure-mobile-apps_src_express_middleware_authenticate.html for more).

And here is a [post](https://shellmonger.com/2016/04/08/30-days-of-zumo-v2-azure-mobile-apps-day-5-custom-authentication/) about custom authentication on Azure Mobile Apps, which maybe can give you any help or hints.